# How can I generate a list based on certain limitation where it takes numbers from infinity and 0 always in middle?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

How can I generate a list based on certain limitation (explained below) where it takes numbers from infinity and 0 always in middle?

for example:

```
NumberOfItem = 5     #this will decide there will be only 5 item in the list 

dfNum= 1     #different between number 

this list should look: 
[-2,-1,0,1,2]
```

another example in the case of an even number the negative will be more than the positive +1 item

```
NumberOfItem = 4     

dfNum= 0.5     

this list should look: 
[-1.0,-0.5,0,0.5,]
```

it is better to find a solution without the use of loop (for.. or while)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to approach it using a list comprehension:

```
[(x - 5 // 2) * 1 for x in range(5)]
[(x - 4 // 2) * 0.5 for x in range(4)]
```

In general:

```
[(x - NumberOfItem // 2) * dfNum for x in range(NumberOfItem)]
```

What you call "difference" can also be seen as "scale factor".

Comment: your answer gave me exactly what I wanted thank you. I thought using (for .. in) will be a problem but it did not. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following function:

```
def make_list(NumberOfItem, dfNum):
    l = map(lambda x:x*dfNum, xrange(-(NumberOfItem/2), (NumberOfItem+1)/2))
    return l
```

Edit:

use it like the following: `my_list = make_list(5,1)`
or `my_list = make_list(4,0.5)` or `print make_list(3,1)`

the first value in the parenthesis is the NumberOfItem and the second one is the dfNum.

Comment: Python 2 --> use `xrange()`.

Comment: @Meccano I am new to python for that I need a little more explanation on what you used. I tried it when I 'print make_list' i get (<function make_list at 0x0000000002BE3C88>). and when I 'print 1' i get (NameError: name '1' is not defined), what is going on?